# Evaluating the limits for $y=(1+\frac{y}{x})^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac{y}{x})^x=e^y$

So I put the following equation on an online graphing calculator :

$$y=(1+\frac{y}{x})^x$$

and got the following graph

[image]

I can understand as $x \to \infty , (1+\frac{y}{x})^x \to e^y$

which would mean as $y \to \infty,e^y \to \infty$

which would imply that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} (1+\frac{y}{x})^x = \infty$ but somehow the graph seems to evetually concede to 1 instead of \infty.

Why does this behave like this?

Comment: Aren't you graphing the solutions of the equation $y=(1+\frac{y}{x})^x$? Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: $y=(1+\frac{y}{x})^x \Rightarrow$ $1+\frac{y}{x}=y^{1/x} \Rightarrow$ $1+yu=y^u$, $u=1/x$. One can prove that at $0<u\leq 1$, $y>0$: $1+yu > y^u$, so there is no solution such that $u \leq 1$, then there is no solution such that $x \geq 1$.

Comment: You cannot use limit $x\to \infty$ for equation $y=(1+y/x)^x$, because there are no such $x$

Comment: Maybe, you wanted to plot something like $y=(1+a/x)^x$ at various values of $a$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}y=e^a$.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu What I did was $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} y= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} (1+\frac{y}{x})^x=\infty$ which is what  thought it would result in....but thanks to your earlier explanation it seems clearer now...